# Unable to read the parquet files present on the Amazon s3 and load into FlinkSql

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, parquet, flink-streaming, flink-sql

**I have succesfully loaded the csv files data from amazon s3 into the FlinkSql local machine**

```
CREATE TABLE fs_table (
  username STRING,
  age STRING
) WITH (
  'connector'='filesystem',
  'path'='s3://d11-data-lake-load/flink/events_data/test_flink/test-csv',
  'format'='csv'
);
```

**The same thing I tried with Parquet files to load from S3 into FlinkSql:** **Getting exceptions**

```
CREATE TABLE fs_table (
  username STRING,
  age STRING
) WITH (
  'connector'='filesystem',
  'path'='s3://d11-data-lake-load/flink/events_data/test_flink/test-parquet',
  'format'='parquet'
);

[INFO] Table has been created.

Flink SQL> select * from fs_table;

[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosName
```

I have included the related jar in the flink classpath, but a new exception comes and this continues forever

Answer (score 1):

In case the flink do not find any filesystem related libraries it will look in the HADOOP classpath. Hence please add below classpath variables in ~/.bash_profile.

**export HADOOP_CLASSPATH= 'hadoop classpath'**

**Looks like this on my machine in ~/.bash_profile:**

```
export HADOOP_HOME="/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop"
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$(find $HADOOP_HOME -name '*.jar' | xargs echo | tr ' ' ':')
```

Also include flink-sql-parquet jar of the same version of the flink(installed) in the lib folder of flink directory. Here it is 1.12.2

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-sql-parquet_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.2</version>
</dependency>
```